# HTML textarea input doesnt recognize line breaks

Tags: php, html, forms, line-breaks

I have a really silly problem, but i cannot find a way to solve it,
I programming a helpdesk system, with support Tickets
I have a form in my website like

```
<form action="somepage.php" action="post">

<input id="reply" type="textarea">

<button id="replyButton" type="submit">Submit</button>

</form>
```

but when the user submits the text, and i show it in the website as the conversation between the user and the support assistant, it doesnt recognize the line breaks, i dont know if its putting \n\r or #10#13, or even nothing...

i've tested and when i press enter in the text area and click submit, when i get that same text from my database i get EMPTY SPACES where the linebreaks should be...

BTW> before displaying the text im using utf8_enconde($text) because people are typing speciales characters like letters with acute and ñ

Comment: The markup `<input id="reply" type="textarea">` is invalid. Browsers treat it as if it had `type=text`, i.e. it creates a *single-line* control, not multi-line control like the `<textarea>` element (unless you are using some odd browser).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In HTML you use the

```
<br>
```

tag for line breaks. Replace all line breaks (newline characters) with said tag and you *should* be fine. You can "convert" line breaks (newline characters) to that tag using [nl2br()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) (it really only insert such tags after line breaks (newline characters).

Comment: yes, but how do i make the text area display or convert the linebreaks to <br> ... ???

Comment: @Gabriel Matusevich Updated the answer to answer your comment.

Comment: yes, that was it!.. .. ill mark the answer as correct in 7 min.. cant do it before o.O!

Answer (score 0):

Escape all special characters before storing it into the database. For instance in MySQL, you can use **mysql_real_escape_string**. This escapes all special characters while storing in the Database.

**mysql_real_escape_string** : http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Then use **nl2br()** while displaying back the content from Database.

**nl2br()** : http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

Comment: True, but you should also sanitize user input from all kinds of other attacks as well, not just database attacks. See XSS for example.