# query - pass <br /> from text area to hidden div for auto-resizing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote a little jquery to resize my text area as you type, and it works fine unless I use a line break.

```
function resize() {
    var value = $('textarea').val();
    var div = $('div');
    div.html(value);

    var height = div.height();
    /// etc. 
}

<div style="display: none;"></div>
<textarea></textarea>
```

The text area and div have the same font and everything, so they align perfectly and the text area resizes accordingly, but when I use a line break (example: "`one<br />two`") the output to the div ignores it ("`one two`"). How do I make it include the line break?

Comment: If the CSS matches exactly, then try adding `white-space:pre;`

Comment: Instead of using `div.html()`, you can try `pre.text()`

Comment: Duplicate? Here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10950538/how-to-detect-line-breaks-in-a-text-area-input or here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19581393/html-textarea-input-doesnt-recognize-line-breaks

Comment: @Mark Of the second, yes.  The first is about counting, though.  I am glad I never read those answers when I built this for myself.  Much easier ways exist. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my fiddle with complete code: http://jsfiddle.net/billccn/8kgpc/1/. Two tricks I used:

- Use a `<pre>` so the linebreak is preserved
- Add a new line during the measurement so that there's always extra space in the textarea

The core code is simple:

```
$(this).height($('pre').text(this.value + '\na').height());
```

In the fiddle, I've changed the text size to show it still work in that case.